# Alias error: using cd command with Git bash

Tags: bash, git, alias

I am trying to add an alias to git to redirect to the project folder, open VS Code and run a local server

my alias:

```
[alias]
     creative = cd e:/work/vero/creative-app/front-end && code . && npm rune serve
```

problem is when run `git creative` response is :

```
expansion of alias 'creative' failed; 'cd' is not a git command
```

Comment: Prepend your alias with `!` for it to be passed to bash.

Comment: IT worked! Thank you, man. Can You add this as an answer and I label it as the right answer and you get the credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prepend a `!` to your alias, and it will be interpreted by bash rather than git directly.

From the [doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) :

```
As you can tell, Git simply replaces the new command with whatever you
alias it for. However, maybe you want to run an external command,
rather than a Git subcommand. In that case, you start the command with
a ! character.
```